# Which interface implement to use an Array of (MyType) as a DataSource?

Tags: .net, linq, datasource

I have a LINQ query like the following:

```
    allRecords = (From metaset In section.sets
                  From metacell In metaset.cells
                  Let attrib = metacell.attrib
                  Order By attrib.attrib_name
                  Select Attribute = attrib.attrib_name,
                         Type = attrib.attrib_name,
                         Col = metacell.column,
                         Row = metacell.row
                     ).ToArray()
```

It return an `<anonymous type>` array.
And when I write `myDataGridView.DataSource = allRecords`, the grid correctly fills.

But, if I modify the query to return an array of `CellDetail` objects, instead of `<anonymous type>`:

```
    allRecords = (From metaset In section.sets
                  From metacell In metaset.cells
                  Let attrib = metacell.attrib
                  Order By attrib.attrib_name
                  Select New CellDetail With {
                         .Attribute = attrib.attrib_name,
                         .Type = attrib.attrib_name,
                         .Col = metacell.column,
                         .Row = metacell.row
                     ).ToArray()
```

where `CellDetail` is so defined:

```
Public Class CellDetail

    Public Attribute As String
    Public Type As String
    Public Col As Int32
    Public Row As Int32

End Class
```

The DataGridView doesn't find compatible data and doesn't show nothing!

Is there a .Net interface I should implement to make `CellDetail` class compatible with the DataSource of a DataGridView?

Comment: Read the remarks for the datasource property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx

Comment: @Munchies which don't actually apply to this question; both sources are arrays, and arrays implement `IList`. That isn't the reason why it works for one and not the other.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yup, I didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView` binds to ***properties***, not ***fields***. Make them properties.

```
Public Class CellDetail    
    Public Property Attribute As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Col As Int32
    Public Property Row As Int32    
End Class
```

Or in C#, this would be:

```
public class CellDetail {    
    public string Attribute {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
    public int Col {get;set;}
    public int Row {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc Gravell... Accepting your answer!